Sandbox: bash(10528) deny(1) file-write-create
Hello have anybody encountered this error before while trying to build xcode?
I have already Put User Script Sandboxing to No and this error is still persisting
Would appreciate any help! Thank you!
Sandbox: bash(10528) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/lxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FoodSafety-ftqljiaxksebjgeyvydyogmntxtw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FoodSafety.app/ip.txt
I using building React-native-CLI

